# How do I test synchronous code called before an async Task method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, xunit.net, nsubstitute

I am attempting to test an `async Task` method that calls synchronous code before and after calling a separate `async Task` method. The synchronous code updates a loading state enumeration that tells the view layer what to display (e.g. a loading spinner when loading, an error message when an exception is thrown, etc.). Note that I have omitted the property changed event in this example for brevity.

```cs
namespace Models
{
    public class DataRepository
    {
        private readonly IDataService dataService;

        public DataRepository(IDataService dataService)
        {
            this.dataService = dataService;
        }

        public LoadingState LoadingState { get; set; }

        public async Task Refresh()
        {
            // Synchronous code to notify view to show loading state
            this.LoadingState = LoadingState.Busy;

            try
            {
                await this.dataService.LoadData();

                // Synchronous code to notify view to show done state
                this.LoadingState = LoadingState.Done;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Synchronous code to notify view to show error state
                this.LoadingState = LoadingState.Error;
            }
        }
    }

    // This is in a separate class in the actual code. Including here for context.
    public enum LoadingState
    {
        Busy,
        Error,
        Done,
    }
}
```

I am using [NSubstitute](https://nsubstitute.github.io/) to mock `IDataService`, [XUnit](https://xunit.net/) to run the tests, and [Fluent Assertions](https://fluentassertions.com/) to assert. I am able to test the loading state value in the following cases:

1. When the `LoadData()` method completes successfully:

```cs
[Fact]
public async void Refresh_Success_ExpectLoadingStateDone()
{
    var mockDataService = Substitute.For<IDataService>();
    var dataRepository = new DataRepository(mockDataService);

    await dataRepository.Refresh();

    dataRepository.LoadingState.Should().Be(LoadingState.Done);
}
```

2. When the `LoadData()` method throws an exception:

```cs
[Fact]
public async void Refresh_ThrowsException_ExpectLoadingStateError()
{
    var mockDataService = Substitute.For<IDataService>();
    mockDataService.Throws<Exception>();
    var dataRepository = new DataRepository(mockDataService);

    await dataRepository.Refresh();

    dataRepository.LoadingState.Should().Be(LoadingState.Error);
}
```

However, I cannot write a test that asserts that the loading state has been set to "Busy".

```cs
[Fact]
public async void Refresh_InitialState_ExpectLoadingStateBusy()
{
    var mockDataService = Substitute.For<IDataService>();
    var dataRepository = new DataRepository(mockDataService);

    await dataRepository.Refresh();

    // This test fails because the loading state is set to "Done" at this point.
    dataRepository.LoadingState.Should().Be(LoadingState.Busy);
}
```

How do I write a test for the initial loading state? Is there a way to pause the call to `LoadData()` so that I can assert on the initial loading state?

Comment: Are you saying that when the `Refresh` call starts, the state should be `Busy` and then it will transition to `Done` once the `Refresh` call completes? How long does it stay busy (nanoseconds, milliseconds, seconds)? You don't have to immediately `await` a task. You can look at its `IsCompleted` property or do a few other things (though I don't think you can _Pause_ it). If the task is not completed, then your state should be `Busy`. But, if it completes quickly, you'll have a hard time catching it busy

Comment: @Flydog57 Yes, that's correct. I want to assert that the state is `Busy` when the `Refresh` call starts. In my production code, `LoadData` actually calls an external web service so I don't know how long it stays busy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mock `LoadData` to return a task managed by you, which will complete when you say so. Then, do not `await Refresh` because for this test you don't need for `Refresh` to complete, you want to check the state in progress. Then after you call `Refresh` (without `await`) the `LoadData` will be in progress and you can verify that state is `Busy`. Then complete the `LoadData` and wait for `Refresh` to complete to finish the test. For example:

```
var mockDataService = Substitute.For<IDataService>();
// this will represent our LoadData in progress
// it won't complete until we tell it
var inProgressTask = new TaskCompletionSource();
// mock LoadData to return this task
mockDataService.Configure().LoadData().Returns(inProgressTask.Task);
var dataRepository = new DataRepository(mockDataService);
// now, execute Refresh but do not await it yet
var pendingRefresh = dataRepository.Refresh();
// assert that state is Busy at this point, as it should be
var state = dataRepository.LoadingState; // Busy
// signal LoadData to complete
inProgressTask.SetResult();
// await Refresh
await pendingRefresh;
```